# ASP.NET Core page cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-core

I have website which is working few months now and i have problem (which started few days back) where sometimes it displays me "This page can't be found". Message shows when i load some page, it doesn't load long (1 - 2 sec) and then show this message. I then refresh page and it sometimes work sometimes not.

What to do? How to investigate?

Comment: First, I would turn on verbose loggning. Then the logs should show the requested url and what controller it tries to route to.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: Take a look at the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: There could be many factors why you are having this problem. I presume the behaviour you are experiencing is in production. Does it happen locally or any other environments you may have? If you have a load balancer in place, it's possible that your traffic is getting redirected to a particular server when it doesn't work for some reason. Please check with your DevOps team if you have one to look for this particular scenario.